# iOS: how to make an image brighter using imagePicker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am making an app that take an photo from the iPad.  We want to be able to adjust the contrast and brightness because the image taken seems kinda dim.  We thought about Overlay, but it looks like it can't make the image brighter but darker.  Any suggestions on how to make it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the category UIImage+Brightness.h provided with  [UIImageAdjust](https://github.com/coryleach/UIImageAdjust)
the category add to uiimage  a very simple methode`- (UIImage*) imageWithBrightness:(CGFloat)brightnessFactor;`

Comment: Hi touti, I'm using the same but it shows error see the code below : 
        CGFloat slideValue = sender.value/2;
    
    
        _modelImg.image=[_modelImg.image imageWithContrast:(CGFloat)slideValue];  the error I'm getting is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage imageWithContrast:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa95b280'..  please help me...